# Bootstrap carousel inner images

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

My carousel is a 1200*500 dimension one. When I put an image of the same dimension , its not taking the full width of the carousel , just partially.

I tried using the "fill" class in my html code but its not working , I also tried with this css code:

```
 .carousel,
 .item,
 .active {
    height: 100%;
}

  .carousel-inner {
    height: 100%;
}
```

Nothing seems to be working. Any help please

HTML Code:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                </ol>
                <div class="carousel-inner">
                    <div class="item active">
                        <img src="images/18.jpg" alt="First slide">
                        <div class="carousel-caption">
                            <h3>
                                First slide</h3>
                            <p>
                                Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue mollis interdum.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                        <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x500/9b59b6/8e44ad" alt="Second slide">
                        <div class="carousel-caption">
                            <h3>
                                Second slide</h3>
                            <p>
                                Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue mollis interdum.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                        <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x500/34495e/2c3e50" alt="Third slide">
                        <div class="carousel-caption">
                            <h3>
                                Third slide</h3>
                            <p>
                                Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue mollis interdum.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide="prev">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span></a><a class="right carousel-control"
                        href="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide="next"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right">
                        </span></a>
            </div>
            <div class="main-text hidden-xs">
                <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
                    <h1>
                        Static Headline And Content</h1>
                    <h3>
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
                    </h3>
                    <div class="">
                        <a class="btn btn-clear btn-sm btn-min-block" href="http://www.jquery2dotnet.com/">Login</a><a class="btn btn-clear btn-sm btn-min-block"
                            href="http://www.jquery2dotnet.com/">Registration</a></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="push">
</div>
```

CSS code:

```
.main-text
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 80px;
    width: 96.66666666666666%;
    color: #FFF;
}
.btn-min-block
{
    min-width: 170px;
    line-height: 26px;
}
.btn-clear
{
    color: #FFF;
    background-color: transparent;
    border-color: #FFF;
    margin-right: 15px;
}
.btn-clear:hover
{
    color: #000;
    background-color: #FFF;
}
#carousel-example-generic
{
    margin-top: 80px;
    min-height: 100px;
    min-width: 80%;
 }
```

Comment: I tried to reproduce the problem that you are going through, but I could not. For me it will be normal the carousel. Can you send a print? Perhaps I can best enteder the problem and help you

Comment: Here's a link of a picture:
http://2.1m.yt/tohtA9N.png

Comment: Now I understand. In your case, the problem is that the proportions of your image is not fitting with the Carousel dimensions. Is there an alternative to this problem, but the structure of your HTML will change a little. It's okay if this happens?

Comment: This example worked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/leonardoaraujocosta/8mLz1rh1/1/) for you (it's a bit simple, but will help you).

The change I made, compared to yours, is that I am now adding the image as background in a DIV, not in an image element. Thus, we can control the display, regardless of the size the image has.

```css
.carousel-img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active">
      <div class="carousel-img" style="background-image: url('http://lorempixel.com/1200/500/')"></div>
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="carousel-img" style="background-image: url('http://lorempixel.com/1200/500/')"></div>
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

I have helped you in any way

Comment: @MatthieuTopize If my answer helped you, click "Accept answer", please :)

Comment: Thanks @MatthieuTopize. Any questions, just let me know!